# cannot access javascript output in android code properly

Tags: javascript, java, android, global-variables, inner-classes

I have used [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) guide for binding JavaScript code to Android code which works properly (a `Toast` message is triggered from javascript code and shows `double` type output of javascript code). My problem is that I cannot use the output in other parts of code. For example, correct outputs are `10, 20, 30, ...`, but what I access in another part of code is `0, 10, 20, 30, ...`.Here is related parts of my code:

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {
    int globalVar;
    .
    .
    .
    //some android code
    .
    .
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_show:
            loadNew();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "globalVar " + String.valueOf(globalVar), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  //after clicking menu item, I receive a double output from javascript, 
  //but first output is zero!!!
        .
    .
    .
    //some android code
    .
    .
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(double toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(toast), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //In this part of code, results are correct
        globalVar =  (int) (toast);
    }
}
```

everytime I click on menu item, a new page is loaded and a javascript code gives a new result.

```
<body onLoad="showAndroidToast();">
```

I think that the problem is originated from accessing variables from inner classes or maybe there is another reason.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, what does your `showAndroidToast()` method look like? Since you have it in the onLoad event, it will execute each time you load the page. So perhaps you should rather have a button and an onClick event handler on your document like `<input type="button" value="Make a Toast" onClick="showAndroidToast('<some-value>')" /><br/>`

Comment: Thank for your answer @ishmaelMakitla. Inside showAndroidToast(), I define a double vaiable and then call Android.showToast(myVar). Using a button will not make any changes because in 'public void showToast(double toast)' I recieve correct results.

Comment: I see, you say you cannot use the output (double values) in another parts of you code - where is this "another part of code" that seems to have incorrect numbers `0, 10, 20, 30, ...`? I am suspecting this is in the Menu-Item-Click function, but just to confirm so I can suggest something...

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla: first click on menu item results in a new page load and triggering JS code, first output should be 10, I receive 10 as the first output inside 'public void showToast(double toast)'. but anyplace outside 'WebAppInterface' class, 'globalVar' is zero. by second click on menu item, output is 20, but now globalVar, outside 'WebAppInterface' class is 10. I hope that the problem would be  now more clarified.

Comment: OK, this makes sense - the issue is that during menu-item-click, `globalVar` has not been set (`0` is default for `int` which you did not initialize) - only when the JS script executes the `showAndroidToast` function - the value of `toast` is received (correctly), and then assigned to variable `globalVar` - so because of this sequence, globalVar will always have a previous value (like `0`, `10`, etc) - so this is an expected behavior. I will post my suggested solution as an answer (limited space on comment).

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla: Excuse me. I editted code. I forgot to write loadnew() method before onOptionsItemSelected which means assign vairiable is done but even in this case, first result is zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110648/discussion-between-ishmaelmakitla-and-objectorientedman).

Answer (score 0):

**//Java End//**

On create of Webview Acivity

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "JSInterface");
```

After that

```
//Class to be injected in Web page
    public class JavaScriptInterface implements JavascriptCallback {
        Context mContext;

        /**
         * Instantiate the interface and set the context
         */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /**
         * Show a toast from the web page
         */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void loadComplete() {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
 // this code will use to show toast from javascript
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
       // this code will use to call a java code from javascript with some parameters.
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void getTimeandDistance(String time, String distance) {

            disTime = "Time: " + time + " | Distance: " + distance;
            runOnUiThread(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        someTextview.setText(disTime);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }));

        }
    }
```

**// Java Script End //**

```
function someFunction(data) {

        var distance = data.route.distance;

        var time = data.route.formattedTime;

         // In this way we call a java code from javascript with some parameters.

         JSInterface.getTimeandDistance(time + "", distance + "");

}
```

and just to show toast you can do this way

```
// write anywhere in your javaScript code
JSInterface.showToast("Show Toast");
```

Comment: Thank for your answer @Hamza Mehmood. JavascriptCallback cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be for you to use some "`listener`" or "`callback`" (pass as a second argument to `WebAppInterface`) which will be notified in `showAndroidToast` method. I created a [Gist of such a listener](https://gist.github.com/ishmaelmakitla/29e2ee147240067da7d09d14adfa0f1c) just add it into your package and update the package names.
Then you update your inner class (`WebAppInterface`) to take the second argument in its constructor:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
     DummyToastListener toastListener;
    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c, DummyToastListener listener) {
        mContext = c;
        toastListener = listener;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(double toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(toast), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        toastListener.onToastValue(toast);
    }
}
```

Then you update `myFragment` class to implement `DummyToastListener` like this:

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment implements DummyToastListener {

   //some where in your code, initializing the WebAppInterface
   //the second argument is also a 'this' because the fragment implements the interface
   webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, this), "Android");
   //implementing the method of the interface DummyToastListener
   @Override
   public void onToastValue(double value){
     //got the new value from Javascript function, do whatever...
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(value), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

 }
```

With this approach, the value from the Javascript function will always be fresh in the `onToastValue` callback method.